# How do you reactive related products on WooCommerce when it has been disabled?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm working on a website and the previous developer disabled Related Products on the WooCommerce theme 'storefront' by adding the following line of code to functions.php:
`remove_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);`

I have commented this out and checked the CSS for a display: none; on the related products container but it doesn't exist.

What else can I check to reactivate related products?

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec I clicked the first Clear Transients button and also clicked update/save on another product and they are still not showing.

Comment: I was just suggesting (may be there is something else somewhere)…

Comment: have you check the Theme Woocommerce options? in Personalize or somewhere there?